# Why does Amazon Music create an asw_sdk{date}.log file on my desktop when it runs?

Tags: windows-10, logging, music

I am running Windows 10 and whenever I run my Amazon Music Desktop app it creates a file called `aws_swk{today's date}.log` file on my desktop. It's always empty. It appears to also have logs in its `AppData\Local\Amazon Music` directory, except they are from a while back. they are also empty.

How do I stop this file from being generated? Or at least change the location it generates in?

Comment: It looks like they are created in the current working directory the amazon music is started in. Still looking for a way to change or suppress them.